# Calculating unknown parts of a right triangle

Tags: java, object-oriented

I am in the process of creating a program that allows a user to input known parts of a right triangle and the calculates all of the unknown parts if it is possible.

I am using a class that I wrote in order to do the calculations. I wanted to know if there is a more efficient solution to this problem or if my code is good as is.

```
public class RightTriangle 
{
    private double sideA; //Leg
    private double sideB; //Leg
    private double sideC; //Hypotenuse 

    private double alpha; 
    private double beta;

    private int numOfSides;
    private int numOfAngles;

    public RightTriangle(double a, double b, double c, double A, double B)
    {
        numOfSides=0;
        numOfAngles=0;

        sideA=a; if(sideA>0){numOfSides++;}
        sideB=b; if(sideB>0){numOfSides++;}
        sideC=c; if(sideC>0){numOfSides++;}

        alpha=A; if(alpha>0){numOfAngles++;}
        beta=B; if(beta>0){numOfAngles++;}

        if(numOfAngles<2)
        {
            findMissingAngles();
        }

        if(numOfSides<3)
        {
            findMissingSides();
        }

        if(!isPossible())
        {
            sideA=sideB=sideC=alpha=beta=0;
        }
    }

    private void findMissingAngles()
    {
        if(alpha==0)
        {
            calcAlpha();
        }

        if(beta==0)
        {
            calcBeta();
        }
    }

    private void findMissingSides()
    {
        if(sideA==0)
        {
            calcSideA();
        }

        if(sideB==0)
        {
            calcSideB();
        }

        if(sideC==0)
        {
            calcSideC();
        }
    }

    private void calcAlpha()
    {
        if(numOfAngles==1)
        {
            alpha=90-beta;
        }

        else
        {
            if(sideA>0 && sideB>0)
            {
                alpha=Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(sideA/sideB));
            }

            else if(sideB>0 && sideC>0)
            {
                alpha=Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(sideB/sideC));
            }

            else if(sideA>0 && sideC>0)
            {
                alpha=Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(sideA/sideC));
            }
        }
    }

    private void calcBeta()
    {
        beta=90-alpha;
    }

    private void calcSideA()
    {
        if(sideC>0)
        {
            sideA=Math.sin(Math.toRadians(alpha)) * sideC;
        }

        else if(sideB>0)
        {
            sideA=Math.tan(Math.toRadians(alpha)) * sideB;
        }
    }

    private void calcSideB()
    {
        sideB=sideA/Math.tan(Math.toRadians(alpha));
    }

    private void calcSideC()
    {
        sideC=sideA/Math.sin(Math.toRadians(alpha));
    }

    private boolean isPossible()
    {
        return ((alpha+beta+90)==180 && Math.abs(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sideA, 2) + Math.pow(sideB, 2)) - sideC) < 1);
    }

    public void printInfo()
    {
        System.out.println("Triangle Info\n");
        System.out.println("Side A: " + String.format("%.02f", sideA));
        System.out.println("Side B: " + String.format("%.02f", sideB));
        System.out.println("Side C: " + String.format("%.02f", sideC) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Alpha: " + String.format("%.01f", alpha));
        System.out.println("Beta: " + String.format("%.01f", beta));
    }
}
```

**Input**

> ```
> Enter Triangle Information (Enter 0 for missing parts)
> Enter side A: 60
> Enter side B: 60
> Enter side C: 0
>
> Enter angle Alpha: 0 
> Enter angle Beta: 0
> ```

**Output**

> ```
> Triangle Info
>
> Side A: 60.00
> Side B: 60.00
> Side C: 84.85
>
> Alpha: 45.0
> Beta: 45.0
> ```

Comment: Could you add a usage example of how to use your code? Also an example input/output would be appreciated. It makes your question both more interesting and easier to review.

Answer (score 1):

#### Keep it simple

> ```
>         numOfSides=0;
>         numOfAngles=0;
>
>         sideA=a; if(sideA>0){numOfSides++;}
>         sideB=b; if(sideB>0){numOfSides++;}
>         sideC=c; if(sideC>0){numOfSides++;}
>
>         alpha=A; if(alpha>0){numOfAngles++;}
>         beta=B; if(beta>0){numOfAngles++;}
>
>         if(numOfAngles<2)
>         {
>             findMissingAngles();
>         }
>
>         if(numOfSides<3)
>         {
>             findMissingSides();
>         }
> ```

This seems more complicated than necessary.  Why have `numOfAngles` and `numOfSides` at all?  You could just say

```
        sideA = a;
        sideB = b;
        sideC = c;

        alpha = A;
        beta = B;

        findMissingAngles();

        findMissingSides();
```

And then modify

> ```
>         if(numOfAngles==1)
> ```

in `calcAlpha` to say

```
        if (beta > 0)
```

That saves two object fields that exist just for construction purposes.

#### Be careful of false modularity

> ```
>     private void calcBeta()
>     {
>         beta=90-alpha;
>     }
> ```

This only works if you calculate `alpha` first.  That's the programming logic here, but nothing enforces it.  So why have a separate method to do an assignment based on one subtraction?  You could change

> ```
>         if(beta==0)
>         {
>             calcBeta();
>         }
> ```

to say

```
        if (beta==0)
        {
            beta = 90 - alpha;
        }
```

instead.  Then you could get rid of `calcBeta`.

This also avoids the problem of calling `calcBeta` without testing that `beta` doesn't already have a value.

Alternately, you could change `calcBeta` to be more like `calcAlpha` where it calculates `alpha` from `beta` if `beta` exists or from two sides otherwise.

Similarly, all the `calcSide` methods assume that `alpha` exists.  And `calcSideB` and `calcSideC` assume that `sideA` exists.  If any of that is not true, then you'll get weird results.

#### Exceptional circumstances

> ```
>     private boolean isPossible()
>     {
>         return ((alpha+beta+90)==180 && Math.abs(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sideA, 2) + Math.pow(sideB, 2)) - sideC) < 1);
>     }
> ```

Why not change `(alpha+beta+90)==180` to just `(alpha + beta) == 90`?

Why is `1` the acceptable error?  Why not .1 or .03 or something else?

Are negative values acceptable?  Because you accept them if they have the right magnitude.  For example, `-95` and `185` are a valid pair of angles.  And `-3`, `-4`, `5` are valid side values.

Answer (score 0):

## Constructor

Do not make calculations in a constructor.

## Responsibilities

As you only have one class of objects that are not communicating to other objects this program can be considered as a procedural program. OOP is about structuring a program by responsibilities. So let's start to identify them.

The purpose of the program is to calculate missing elements of a right triangle. So you have

1. Some information with that you may or may not be able to construct a right triangle
2. An algorithm that identifies if a construction with the given information is possible
3. A strategy to calculates missing elements
4. A representation of a valid right triangle

Each of the responsibilities should be represented in a separated code fragment, a method or a class.

## 1

To calculate missing elements of a right triangle you have to have at least two more information beside GAMMA that is considered to be 90 degrees. Given angles must be in a range of 0 > angle < 90 and edges must be x > 0. You have to decide what to do with redundant and compromising information.I suggest to throw an exception if something is strange.

## 2

I do not really understand the isPossible()-method. It is called AFTER every calculation and it is calculating something I don't really want to understand. The isPossible() check has to be called as early as possible.

In my reality I first check if something can be done and maybe then it is done. In this case I would first check what I described in (1).

Often if you do things not in the "natural order" you mess up your code.

## 3

Here you have to identify a strategy to calculate missing information.

You have a lot of if statements to identify the next calculation. That's because you have redundant code that isn't obvious. Look at this:

```
Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(sideB/sideC));
Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(sideA/sideC));
```

As ALPHA and BETA are complementary angles this can be written as:

```
90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(sideB/sideC));
Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(sideA/sideC));
```

So the Math.asin() is redundant.

Here again some redundant code:

```
private void calcAlpha()
{
    if(numOfAngles==1)
    {
        alpha=90-beta;
    }
...

private void calcBeta()
{
    beta=90-alpha;
}
```

Only the names are different but the calculation is the same.

Normally you have 7 cases of given information:

1. a and b
2. a and c
3. b and c
4. a and alpha
5. b and alpha
6. a and beta
7. b and beta

There is a symmetry you can make use of for this special right triangle case. I suggest to first remember the given names and then "normalize" the given information. After that you are able to reduce the possible cases to 4:

1. a and b (alpha, beta and c missing)
2. a and c (alpha, beta and b missing)
3. a and alpha (beta, b and c missing)
4. a and beta (alpha, b and c missing)

You only have to remember if the names were switched (normalized).

> Normalization is a mechanism so transform information into a state so
>   that an algorithm can rely on certain well defined properties. In this
>   case we eliminate redundancies as it is done within the normalization
>   process of database schemas.

## 4

At last you have to only have to construct a right triagle with the normalized information.

```
public class RightTriangle {

    private double a;
    private double b;
    private double alpha;

    public RightTriangle(double a, double b, double alpha) {
        super();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.alpha = alpha;
    }

    public double getAlpha() {
        return alpha;
    }

    public double getBeta() {
        return 90.0 - getAlpha();
    }

    public double getGamma() {
        return 90.0;
    }

    public double getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public double getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public double getC() {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(getA(), 2) + Math.pow(getB(), 2));
    }

}
```